# Converting items in Visual Studio project from "links" to copied files

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio (2008) project where I have some files added as links (through Add Existing Item->Add As Link). Suppose I want to copy this project somewhere else (give it to another developer, release source code, etc.) and I would like to "convert" all these links to actual copies of these files. Is this possible? How can I do this in VS or is there some 3rd party utility to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met this exactly problem, and wrote a little tool to do this.
Checkout: http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnblogs.com%2Fdeerchao%2Farchive%2F2010%2F04%2F22%2F1718183.html&sl=zh-CN&tl=en

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the easiest approach is simply to remove the items from your project and then add them again, but not as links? If you want to keep the files as links in your project, make the copy first and then remove/add the items in the copy.

Comment: Well, I know that I can do that :) The reason I'm asking is that this doesn't sound like an appealing approach to me.

Comment: I understand; might, if nothing else, be a bit tedious if it is a large number of files...

Answer (score 0):

if all your files are under a single root (and not c:\...) and relative you can try use [TreeTrim](http://code.google.com/p/treetrim/).

*treetrim.console c:\ -workingcopy -zip:writeTo:c:\out.zip*

this will create a zip will all the need info without the temporary files (.pdb, .ncb)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow how this would help in my situation?

Comment: you don't need to convert the links if they are relative. just send the entire root folder. you can use trim tree to clean the files you don't need. If your files are not relative then they should, there should be at least one common root for all the files